# get data from file and vector

Tags: c++, file, vector

I want to retrieve all the data inside the text file, so I will read to vector 1st then display all the data out. The 1st data in the text file I can get it properly, but the 2nd data in the text file, the username can't be retrieve and it gone.
Here's the text file data...

1|admin|admin|admin|Male|123|123|123|

1|jeff|jeff|jeff|Male|123|123|123|

And after I display all the data out...it become like this

1 admin admin admin Male 123 123 123

1 jeff jeff Male 123 123 123

Can anyone help me to solve?? THANKS

```
void Admin::displayMemberInfo(vector <Member> &memberProfile)
{
if(loginSucceed == true)
{
    int memberID, age;
    string username, password, name, gender, contact, ic;
    memberProfile.erase(memberProfile.begin(),memberProfile.end());
    ifstream inMember("Member.txt");
        while(!(inMember.eof()))
        {
            string name,gender,contact, ic, username, password;
            int age,memberID;
            string readID,readAge;
            getline(inMember,readID,'|');
            istringstream(readID)>>memberID;
            getline(inMember,username,'|');
            getline(inMember,password,'|');
            getline(inMember,name,'|');
            getline(inMember,gender,'|');
            getline(inMember,readAge,'|');
            istringstream(readAge)>>age;
            getline(inMember,contact,'|');
            getline(inMember,ic,'|');
            inMember.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '|');
            //if(username != "")
            //{
            //  Member member(memberID, username, password, name, gender,age, contact, ic);
            //  memberProfile.push_back(member);
            //}
            cout<<memberID<<username<<password<<name<<gender<<age<<contact<<ic<<endl;
        }
        inMember.close();
        system("pause");
}
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Chemistpp It does not display out the data properly

Comment: well, you aren't adding any spaces.

`cout << memberID << " " <<`...  You do not put any spaces in the output stream.  What is your output and what is your intended output?

Comment: @Chemistpp That space doesn't affect anything, problem is the username of jeff was not printed out. What's the problem actually?

Comment: I see it now.  Only two jeffs print.  Okay, let me check.

Comment: @Chemistpp thanks for your help =) appreciate

Comment: I downvoted because I thought your question was unclear, if you accept my edit, then I can remove my downvote

Comment: @Chemistpp it's okay, as long as you helped me, it doesn't matter =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line

`inMember.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '|');`

to

`inMember.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Oh yeah, I forgot, you redeclare variables.

Try this entire function and tell me if it works better:

```
void Admin::displayMemberInfo(/* vector <Member> &memberProfile */) {

int memberID, age;
string username, password, name, gender, contact, ic;

//memberProfile.erase(memberProfile.begin(),memberProfile.end());

ifstream inMember("Members.txt");
if(inMember.fail()) return;
while(!(inMember.eof())) {
    string readID,readAge;
    getline(inMember,readID,'|');
    istringstream(readID)>>memberID;
    getline(inMember,username,'|');
    getline(inMember,password,'|');
    getline(inMember,name,'|');
    getline(inMember,gender,'|');
    getline(inMember,readAge,'|');
    istringstream(readAge)>>age;
    getline(inMember,contact,'|');
    getline(inMember,ic,'|');
    inMember.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    //if(username != "")
    //{
    //  Member member(memberID, username, password, name, gender,age, contact, ic);
    //  memberProfile.push_back(member);
    //}
    cout<<memberID<<username<<password<<name<<gender<<age<<contact<<ic<<endl;
}
inMember.close();
system("pause");
}
```

You were also re-declaring variables in the function as well as the while loop.
I commented out the vector stuff for my test.

My input file is

```
1|admin|admin|admin|Male|123|123|123|
2|jeff|jeff|jeff|Male|123|123|123|
```

Terminated with a new line.  The output is

```
1adminadminadminMale123123123
2jeffjeffjeffMale123123123
```

Comment: yes. The username of jeff is came out! But there's pop out a new line...and it appear only 123 at the password column...

Comment: So, we need to discuss your input a bit better. Is your input format guarenteed?  New line between member data, does it end with a new line?

Comment: yes...my input is like this
`outMember<<member.getMemberID()<<'|'<<member.getUsername()<<'|'<<member.getPassword()<<'|'<<member.getName()<<'|'<<member.getGender()<<'|'<<member.getAge()<<'|'<<member.getContactNumber()<<'|'<<member.getICNumber()<<'|'<<endl;`

Comment: omg...you are awesome! Thanks for the help man. APPRECIATE. =D